# excel vba tabstrip is it possible to left align the tab captions?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a tabstrip, with a couple of tabs with

```
.style = fmTabStyleButtons
.TabOrientation = fmTabOrientationLeft
```

I can't seem find anything to change the alignment of the button captions. The captions are all justified within the button. With `.font` I can change the font, the weight and the size, but no alignment.

Is it possible at all? A solution without vba would also be ok.

Thx Kaz

Comment: Only by adding spaces to the end of the tab names. The tabs are sized to fit the text (not vice versa).